# Trying pipe in a list of CSV in to import CSV

Tags: powershell

So I am trying to pipe in a file list into import CSV:

```
ls *.csv | select FullName | where FullName -NotMatch "fixed" | ForEach-Object {
    Import-Csv -Path %($_.FullName) -Delimiter ";"
}
```

But I am getting this error:

```
Import-Csv : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument
'C:\***\Documents\Daraz Order\order.list.export 2019-11-13.csv'.
At line:2 char:1
+ Import-Csv -Path %($_.FullName) -Delimiter ";"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Import-Csv], ParameterBindingException
     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportCsvCommand
```

It gives the same error for all the files in the list. I have tried the `ToString()` method. But the error persist:

```
+ Import-Csv -Path %($_.FullName.ToString()) -Delimiter ";"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Import-Csv], ParameterBindingException
     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportCsvCommand
```

What might be causing this?

Comment: Remove the `%` from `%($_.FullName)`.

Comment: I tried doing that I am getting `A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'System.Object[]'.`

I tried `ToString` method as well. Same Error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems some idiosyncrasy of PowerShell 6. I just decided to use a code block and just pipes. The code that worked for me was:

```
ls *.csv| select FullName,BaseName | where FullName -NotMatch "fixed"| foreach {
$file = $_.FullName.ToString()
$bname = $_.BaseName.ToString()
$bnamepath = ".\$bname-fixed.csv"
Import-Csv $file -Delimiter ';' | Export-Csv $bnamepath -Delimiter ','
}
```

I still had to do a pipe at the end because keeping the data in a variable causes the output file just have the object properties and not the values of the other CSV. This script will work if you wan to process the files in Excel without changing your system's locale.

Answer (score 2):

The answer Patrick gave you is correct. However you still get the error. You should try different methods of troubleshooting (using Powershell_ISE obviously).

```
$import = @()
ls *.csv| select FullName | where FullName -NotMatch "fixed" | foreach-object {
    $path = $_.FullName
    $path.GetType()
    $path
    try{
        Get-Content -Path $path
    }catch{
        Write-Host "Path does not exist"
    }
    $import += Import-Csv -path $path -delimiter ";"
}
```

In the above example, to make sure we don't get distracted, we put all the content in the import array. Next look at the path, does it exist? Can you obtain the content of the file? Let's look at the type of the file by trying .GetType().

The error basically says that Import-CSV does not except your argument. So try fixing Import-CSV with a valid path to see if you get it to work first.

PS: Your script does actually work on my system (PowerShell 5.1).

Comment: I am using powershell 6. I did end up not trying to do it one line and instead just use a code block with variables and it works. I'll add the answer later.